# How to use "org.hibernate.envers.default_schema" in custom RevisionEntity

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am using hibernate-envers 4.2.8 and have created my own CustomRevisionEntity to add the user that made the change like this

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity(CustomRevisionEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "REVINFO")
public class CustomRevisionEntity {
...
}
```

and I changed the schema for the auditing tables by adding

```
<prop key="org.hibernate.envers.default_schema">myschema_audit</prop>
```

to my application context.

The auditing tables are all created in schema `myschema_audit` but the `REVINFO` table is unfortunately still created in default schema `myschema`.

Is that because of my `@Table` annotation? Do I have to add the `schema` attribute? If so, how can I use the corresponding hibernate property in that annotation?

I've tried to omit the `@Table` annotation but the `REVINFO` table is not created then at all.

How can I achieve that the `REVINFO` table is created in `myschema_audit`?

Answer (score 2):

If you omit the `@Table` annotation, it likely will be created as `CustomRevisionEntity` or similar based on the naming strategy used by ORM when a `@Table` annotation is not present.

By specifying `@Table(name = "REVINFO", schema = "myschema_audit")`, that should properly place the entity in the right schema with the desired name of `REVINFO`.

HTH.

Comment: You're right regarding ommiting the `@Table` annotation.

I don't want to specify the schema hard coded, but want to use the corresponding hibernate property instead as its value changes depending on maven profiles. Any idea how to do so?

Comment: There is no automated way within Hibernate to do that because a custom revision entity is technically just an ORM entity and therefore it follows the rules of ORM.  Envers in this case just ties into that entity and knows how to insert rows to it during audited events.  What I think you could do is to apply a maven resource substitution pass before compile to accomplish this.  That of course does come with its own drawbacks and concerns however.

Comment: One thing I could look into is whether its possible to _alter_ the schema of the revision entity during the Envers pass if the user is using a custom revision entity and set its schema/catalog to follow that of Envers rules and not that of ORM.

Comment: You have some more information about that? I have same problem with multiple schemas and a custom audit entity that doesnt go into the right schema. :(